# Fish Shell STDERR not outputted by default

Tags: shell, fish

I am using the `fish` shell, which until this moment had been a perfect replacement of the good old `bash`, but I came across the following problem.

`fish` does not forward `STDERR` to `STDOUT`. Of course if I append `^^&1` *(forwards stderr to stdout)* to the command that I am running everything is ok, but that is not the default behaviour.

**Example:**

```
user@Computer ~> rm non_existing_file
user@Computer ~ [1]> rm non_existing_file ^&1
rm: non_existing_file: No such file or directory
user@Computer ~ [1]>
```

How do I fix that?

*P.S. FTR I am running on OS X Mavericks*

Comment: It *should not* be the default behaviour.

Comment: @glennjackman I know, but it is!

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question. Given this command `sh -c 'echo stdout; echo stderr >&2' >/dev/null` what output do you expect to see?

Comment: @glennjackman `rm non_existing_file` returns 1, but does NOT output anything. Only when I explicitly forward stderr to stdout of the command, like this: `rm non_existing_file ^&1` I get: `rm: non_existing_file: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I wonder if this is a terminal issue. I think you should raise an Issue at https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/

Comment: @glennjackman https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2115

Answer (score 1):

Following up on your github comments, I see that the problem was how you use `rvm` integration into fish. I use this: https://rvm.io/integration/fish

```
curl -L --create-dirs -o ~/.config/fish/functions/rvm.fish https://raw.github.com/lunks/fish-nuggets/master/functions/rvm.fish
```

and then add this to config.fish to load the rvm settings into the shell

```
rvm current >/dev/null
```

Comment: That solution is not 100% effective since the community is only just rewriting the RVM scripts for `fish`. Thus problems may occur. The alternative solution is much more effective, since it just builds the RVM environment through `bash`.

Comment: I've posted a fixed "alternative" solution here: https://gist.github.com/itay-grudev/570d3830a651f40b0347

Comment: P.S. I also wrote to RVM with a request to update their link.

Comment: The solution I posted does delegate to bash. While in the bash session, it writes out the environment to a temp file, then in fish, extracts the relevant variables into fish's environment.

Comment: Well I still think the other solution is much more clean. (6 lines of code. No tmp files..) Don't you agree?

Comment: Well, on one hand "it's clean", on the other "it works". I think "fish -> bash -> fish" is pretty nasty.